# How to set the standard Persian keyboard via a Set-WinUserLanguageList PowerShell command?

Tags: powershell, keyboard-layout

In PowerShell’s `Set-WinUserLanguageList` command when I set `LanguageList` to `fa` my Keyboard layout changed to the legacy windows Persian keyboard layout.

But I need standard Persian keyboard layout.

What code must I use instead of `fa`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all type this on your PowerShell:

```
Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList "en-US", "fa-IR" -Force
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I believe the answer is basically to use `fa-IR` instead of plain `fa`? Please clarify if that is the key here because if that is that, then that is the answer.